# How to use css selector path for selenium to get an attribute of an span class - python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to get the `title` attribute from the span class = `g47SY lOXF2` but I can't find the correct css path.

Here is what I tried:

```
Number = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('ul li a span').get_attribute('title')
```

but it does not work.

Here is the HTML:

[image: Here is the HTML]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the **title** *attribute* i.e **251** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href$='followers/']>span[title]"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'followers') and contains(., 'followers')]/span"))).get_attribute("title"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```